# Combining Persistent with RIO logging to dump a table

Tags: haskell, persistent, conduit, rio

I'm writing a toy example to learn Haskell database access with the Persistent library. To play around, I want to see what's in the DB (SQLite in Memory):

```
import qualified Database.Persist.Sql          as PSQL
import qualified Data.Conduit.List             as CL
import           Data.Conduit                   ( ($$) )
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class         (liftIO)

dumpTable :: Text -> IO ()
dumpTable tableName = PSQL.rawQuery "select * from " <> tableName [] $$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . print)
```

(Taken from the School of Haskell)

Because I want to use the RIO libraries for my applications, the above does not work: I need to use one of the RIO logging functions instead of print, and the function must run in the RIO monad. Here is my attempt to do so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
[..]

import           RIO
import qualified Database.Persist.Sql          as PSQL
import           Data.Conduit                   ( ($$) )
import qualified Data.Conduit.List             as CL

dumpTable :: (HasLogFunc env) => Text -> RIO env ()
dumpTable tableName =
    let query = "select * from " <> tableName
    in  PSQL.rawQuery query [] $$ CL.mapM_ (logInfo . displayShow)
```

However, this code does not type check. I get the following error:

```
    • Could not deduce (PSQL.BackendCompatible PSQL.SqlBackend env)
        arising from a use of ‘PSQL.rawQuery’
      from the context: HasLogFunc env
        bound by the type signature for:
                   dumpTable :: forall env. HasLogFunc env => Text -> RIO env ()
        at src/Persistence/DbInspect.hs:13:1-51
    • In the first argument of ‘($$)’, namely ‘PSQL.rawQuery query []’
      In the expression:
        PSQL.rawQuery query [] $$ CL.mapM_ (logInfo . displayShow)
      In the expression:
        let query = "select * from " <> tableName
        in PSQL.rawQuery query [] $$ CL.mapM_ (logInfo . displayShow)
   |
16 |     in  PSQL.rawQuery query [] $$ CL.mapM_ (logInfo . displayShow)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I do not understand what this error means. It would be great if someone could give me some hints on how to go ahead and analyse this error, thereby improving my understanding of the involved typeclasses and monads.

Comment: I have the same issue. Let's see if someone can help us with that

Comment: I found out that there is a package https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio-orphans-0.1.1.0/docs/RIO-Orphans.html which contains monadlogger instance for RIO. That should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly instead of

```
dumpTable :: Text -> IO ()
dumpTable tableName = PSQL.rawQuery "select * from <> tableName" [] $$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . print)
```

you probably want this

```
dumpTable :: Text -> IO ()
dumpTable tableName = PSQL.rawQuery ("select * from " <> tableName) [] $$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . print)
```

Now assuming this version, what you have done here is you have selected a concrete type `IO` for `dumpTable` which **should not** type check.

The function should be written like this

```
dumpTable
  :: (MonadResource m, MonadReader env m,
      BackendCompatible SqlBackend env) =>
     Text -> m ()
dumpTable tableName = PSQL.rawQuery ("select * from " <> tableName)  [] $$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . print)
```

I don't know which specific example you might be referring to but a simple example for `runQuery` would look something like this

```
main :: IO ()
main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
    buildDb
    dumpTable

buildDb
  :: ReaderT SqlBackend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO)) (Key Tutorial)
buildDb = do
    runMigrationSilent migrateTables
    insert $ Tutorial "Basic Haskell" "https://fpcomplete.com/school/basic-haskell-1" True
    insert $ Tutorial "A monad tutorial" "https://fpcomplete.com/user/anne/monads" False
    insert $ Tutorial "Yesod usage" "https://fpcomplete.com/school/basic-yesod" True
    insert $ Tutorial "Putting the FUN in functors" "https://fpcomplete.com/user/anne/functors" False
    insert $ Tutorial "Basic Haskell" "https://fpcomplete/user/anne/basics" False


dumpTable
  :: ReaderT SqlBackend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO)) ()
dumpTable = rawQuery "select * from Tutorial" [] $$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . print)
```

Above example is from [Dumping a table](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/persistent-db#dumping-a-table)

Without going into too much details, the way to satisfy these constraints `ReaderT SqlBackend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO))`  is by using each monad transformers' `run` functions. For `ReaderT` that would be `runReaderT` i.e. `runReaderT configData $ monadReaderConstraiendFunction`.

Anyways, you might want to take a look at how `Monad Transformers` work before diving into this library. It won't take too long, and once you get the gist of it you'll be able to debug any further problems.

Speaking of which, now lets take a look at this part of the error message

```
• Could not deduce (PSQL.BackendCompatible PSQL.SqlBackend env)
    arising from a use of ‘PSQL.rawQuery’
  from the context: HasLogFunc env
```

and your function type

```
dumpTable :: (HasLogFunc env) => Text -> RIO env ()
```

The monad `env` is constrained on `HasLogFunc` but the function `rawQuery` requires several other *contexts* to work in as we saw above.

You can see that from `rawQuery`'s function type `(MonadResource m, MonadReader env m, BackendCompatible SqlBackend env)`.

Basically we need to help GHC out by explicitly defining those in its type signature. I don't know how you're interacting with the `RIO` monad, but the most general case should look like this

```
dumpTable :: (HasLogFunc env
             , PSQL.BackendCompatible PSQL.SqlBackend env
             , MonadResource (RIO env)
             )
          => Text
          -> RIO env ()
dumpTable tableName =
    let query = "select * from " <> tableName
    in  PSQL.rawQuery query [] $$ CL.mapM_ (logInfo . displayShow)
```

Now this will type check.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed explanation! My takeaway is that there seems to be a more general problem with the stack ReaderT - LoggerT - ResourceT - RIO. RIO is ReaderT over IO. The above stacks another ReaderT on top, with more transformers in between, while RIO advocates a typeclass approach to add effects. I don't understand how these two approaches fit together - which is surprising, as they are written by the same author. So, I guess I am missing something here.

Comment: You could try sequentially "unwrapping" each transformer. `dumpTable` will need to be constrained on generic `m` which you can unwrap inside `RIO` which isn't itself a transformer. Something like `{- query runner function -} $ flip ($) appConfig . runReaderT . {- more unwrapping -} . runReaderT {- backend -}`